# java.io.FileNotFoundException: Output.txt (Too many open files)

Tags: java

I have seen this question asked here before, but I do not see the problem at all in my code:

```
public static void append(String text) {
    try (FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter("Output.txt", true);
         BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(fileWriter);
         PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(bufferedWriter);) {
        out.println(text);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Since I am using the try-with-resources statement, the opened files should automatically be closed.

I also tried it the old fashioned way, but that still threw the same error:

```
public static void append(String text) {
    try {
        FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter("Output.txt", true);
        BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(fileWriter);
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(bufferedWriter);
        out.println(text);
        out.close();
        bufferedWriter.close();
        fileWriter.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I do not want to increase the opened file limit, since this code shouldn't have more than 1 file open at any time anyway. No multithreading in my program btw.

Comment: Can you show us how exactly this piece of code is being used ? The issue is somehow your fileWriter is getting created again and again

Comment: (1) What operation system do you use? (2) how many files are really opened before your `append` (3) your 'old style code' miss `finally` block

Comment: The old fashioned way uses a `finally` block to close resources. You don't do it within the try.

Answer (score 0):

"Too many open files", so basically `-EMFILE` in Unix parlance.

We will suppose here Java 7+. And your first problem is that you don't handle the closing of your resources properly, so we will transform your code so that it use java.nio.file instead, plus try-with-resources:

```
public static void append(final String text)
{
    final Path path = Paths.get("Output.txt");
    try (
        final BufferedWriter writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(path,
            StandardCharsets.UTF_8, StandardOpenOption.APPEND);
    ) {
        writer.write(text);
        writer.newLine();
    }
}
```

Also, why do you open a new file descriptor each time you append a line? That is, I believe, the main issue.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer!
The first code that I posted uses the try-with-resources. I will try the code you posted and will get back here once the program ran without the error. Might take some hours.
Thanks again =)

Comment: That there is an answer is one thing; now, does it solve your problem? But like I said, I believe this is a XY problem anyway.

Comment: After implementing your solution, I still get the same error, now just in the nio package...
java.nio.file.FileSystemException: Output.txt: Too many open files

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing with your first code snippet, it should work.
My best guess is that your JVM does not have sufficient permissions to access the file in question. If you are starting your program via a shell script check the start up location maybe you do not have rw permissions on that directory only execute permissions. Also often the answer is what it says it is, maybe there are other intensive processes on the machine that this code is running on, so maybe trying running this else where and check.